# webgl: bufferData freezes my application, how to do it asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webgl, web-worker

I am working on a web 2d world generation and simulation. I generate a 2d terrain (different cell shapes and colors) using perlin noise and some random function in different web workers. Those workers feed a cache which contains the different chunks and their data. When a chunk receives data from its worker, it automatically updates its buffer:

```js
(chunk) => {
                this.webgl.bindBuffer(this.webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, chunk.vertexBuffer);
                this.webgl.bufferData(this.webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, chunk.vertexes, this.webgl.STATIC_DRAW);
                this.webgl.bindBuffer(this.webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, chunk.colorBuffer);
                this.webgl.bufferData(this.webgl.ARRAY_BUFFER, chunk.colors, this.webgl.STATIC_DRAW);
            }
```

I also have a kind of game loop which calls itself at every `requestAnimationFrame` and draw its chunk.

```js
    cache.forEachChunk(center.current, scale.current, (chunk) => {
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, chunk.colorBuffer);
        const fillColor = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "fillColor");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(fillColor);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(fillColor, 3,
            gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, chunk.vertexBuffer);
        const position = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(position);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(position, 2,
            gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        if (chunk.vertexes)
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, chunk.vertexes.length / 2);
    })
```

This works very well ...except that there is a little freeze every time a chunk receives data from its workers: in fact calling bufferData is pretty slow but above all, it is blocking my application. Is there any way to do this in a web worker or any other strategy to be able to send data to my graphics card without blocking my whole application? Blocking it doesn't make sense: the graphics card should still be able to draw the other chunks without worry.

Answer (score 0):

`bufferData` creates a completely new data store. Think of it as buffer allocation and initialization. If you just want to update an existing buffer, use `bufferSubData` (see also [Buffer objects](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.14.5)). `bufferSubData` simply writes the data into an existing buffer without re-creating the data store, so it's much faster. Of course, `bufferSubData` cannot change the size of the data memory and you have to "allocate" the buffer once with `bufferData`. However, there is no need to pass data to the buffer when you initialize it. This means that the *data* argument of `bufferData` can be `null`.

Comment: But I do not want to update an existing buffer: I have one buffer per chunk with its own set of polygons (which is completely static that's why I can pass the data to it when creating it).